# Why is a simple RGB to Lab conversion much slower using compute capability 1.3 than 1.0 even with -use_fast_math flag?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am using GT 740M (CC 3.5) and I have a RGB to Lab conversion kernel. Using compute capability 1.0 - 1.2 the whole kernel is executed in 924 microseconds however using the compute capability of 1.3 or higher (up to 3.5) the kernel is executed in around 3 ms. According to the table from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications I found out that it could be caused by the double-precision floating-point operations so I used the -use_fast_math flag, but it did not help.

What can be the reason of the performance hit?

The whole source code can be seen in http://pastebin.com/JjhH101y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cc 1.0 - 1.2 devices do not support double-precision floating point operations.  Those operations will be "demoted" to single precision floating point operations on those devices.

At first glance, all of your variables are `float` not `double`, but your constants are all double-precision constants.

Therefore arithmetic like this:

```
a=(x-y)*500.0;
```

will involve a double-precision floating point multiply on compile targets that support it (which will be subsequently reduced to a `float`).  On compile targets that don't support it, the above operation will be handled entirely via single-precision math.

The `--use-fast-math` option does not affect conversion between `double` and `float` as discussed above.

I would suggest that you start by decorating all your constants as floating-point constants:

```
a=(x-y)*500.0f;
```

You might also want to carefully review the [CUDA math api](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html) to be sure that you get what you want from operations like this:

```
exp(log(x)/3.0)
```

in terms of single or double-precision arithmetic.

Comment: Instead of `exp(log(x)/3.0)` I would suggest using `cbrt(x)`.

Comment: Thank you Robert, it helps. Now the execution time is 0.472 ms.
njuffa I tried to replace it with cbrt, but it has not affect the execution time, however I will check whether it has impact to the precision, thanks both of you.

Comment: @Dave now looking at the full code on pastebin, your code looks memory bound. Try `const uchar4* __restrict__ inputImg, float4* __restrict__ outputImg`, that may help optimize the memory accesses. Generally `cbrt(x)` should be both faster and more accurate than `exp(log(x)/3))`.

Comment: But my image is 640x480 and the constant memory of GT 740m is only 64KiB, so does it have any sense to use `const __restrict__` ? Thank you.

Comment: `const __restrict__` isn't the same thing as `__constant__` or constant memory.  `const __restrict__` helps a compiler make optimizations in general and may help to enable use of the [read only cache](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-3-0) on supported devices.

Comment: I found out that my GT 740M only support max CC 3.0 and am I right that the `const __restrict__` is supported only from CC 3.5?

Comment: `const __restrict__` is supported everywhere.  Whether or not it leads the compiler to generate read only cache accesses will depend on your device, and your code.  You are correct that read only cache access in this fashion can only be enabled on cc 3.5 or higher devices.